# When archiving: A struct gives "Redundant protocol error", but not when running

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I have migrated the code to Swift 4.2. And when compiling to run on the device all is working fine (compiles and runs). But when I try to archive for TestFlight it gives me the error "Redundant conformance of 'FormEncoding' to protocol 'ParameterEncoding'" for a struct, where there is only one protocol assigned

```
import Foundation
import Moya
import Alamofire

public struct FormEncoding: ParameterEncoding { // Error is here!

    public static var `default`: ParameterEncoding {
        return FormEncoding()
    }

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        ...
    }
```

In the error pane it mentions only single conformance to the protocol:

"'FormEncoding' declares conformance to protocol 'ParameterEncoding' here"

I can imagine that the build settings for Archiving/Release is different and include some additional optimizations/checks. But I don's see an actual error here.

Would appreciate any suggestions how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is due to conflict between Moya and Alamofire. Moya redefines (typealias) the ParameterEncoding:

```
public typealias ParameterEncoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding
```

So if I comment out

```
import Foundation
//import Moya
import Alamofire
```

then it works (archives)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve the issue by referencing the Alamofire's protocol explicitly by using: `public struct FormEncoding: Alamofire.ParameterEncoding { ...`